# Jmeter-How to copy files from one AWS S3 bucket to another bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, jmeter

I have tar.zip files placed in newbucket of AWS S3 location. I have script which will cut the file  and place it in another S3 bucket. Every time I need to upload the files from local to newbucket as JSSR preprocessor to upload the files from local. Can I do copy paste of file in S3 from one bucket to another bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "official" way is to use [AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) in general and [`aws s3 sync` command in particular](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/move-objects-s3-bucket/):

```
aws s3 sync s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-SOURCE s3://DOC-EXAMPLE-BUCKET-TARGET
```

The command can be kicked off either from JSR223 Sampler or from the [OS Process Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter/)

If you prefer doing this programmatically - check out [Copy an Object Using the AWS SDK for Java](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectUsingJava.html) article, the code snippet just in case:

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CopyObjectSingleOperation {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String sourceKey = "*** Source object key *** ";
        String destinationKey = "*** Destination object key ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .build();

            // Copy the object into a new object in the same bucket.
            CopyObjectRequest copyObjRequest = new CopyObjectRequest(bucketName, sourceKey, bucketName, destinationKey);
            s3Client.copyObject(copyObjRequest);
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process 
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client  
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: By using above code I can copy up to 5 gb size files , how do I copy more than 5 gb size  files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket , for example I have to copy 10 gb size file from one s3 bucket to another s3 bucket , how to copy ?