# Jmeter- How to copy Large files from S3 bucket to another bucket in same s3

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to run the performance script which has API which takes the payload as file from S3 and submit to target system. As the JSSR preprocessor i have added the code.([Jmeter-How to copy files from one AWS S3 bucket to another bucket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65561211/jmeter-how-to-copy-files-from-one-aws-s3-bucket-to-another-bucket))

This will copy file upto 5 GB. It will not allow to copy larger files where as i need to test for 15 GB. Please suggest how to perform for more than 5 GB file

Answer (score 0):

Looking into **[Q: How much data can I store in Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/)**

> Upload an object in a single operation using the AWS SDKs, REST API, or AWS CLI—With a single PUT operation, you can upload a **single object up to 5 GB in size.**

from the same page:

> Upload an object in parts using the AWS SDKs, REST API, or AWS CLI—Using the **multipart upload API**, you can upload a single large object, **up to 5 TB in size.**

So you need to switch to [Multipart Upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpuoverview.html), there is even a piece of [example code](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/mpu-upload-object.html):

```
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManager;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.TransferManagerBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.transfer.Upload;

import java.io.File;

public class HighLevelMultipartUpload {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Regions clientRegion = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
        String bucketName = "*** Bucket name ***";
        String keyName = "*** Object key ***";
        String filePath = "*** Path for file to upload ***";

        try {
            AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                    .withRegion(clientRegion)
                    .withCredentials(new ProfileCredentialsProvider())
                    .build();
            TransferManager tm = TransferManagerBuilder.standard()
                    .withS3Client(s3Client)
                    .build();

            // TransferManager processes all transfers asynchronously,
            // so this call returns immediately.
            Upload upload = tm.upload(bucketName, keyName, new File(filePath));
            System.out.println("Object upload started");

            // Optionally, wait for the upload to finish before continuing.
            upload.waitForCompletion();
            System.out.println("Object upload complete");
        } catch (AmazonServiceException e) {
            // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
            // it, so it returned an error response.
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
            // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In case of JMeter's [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/) you either need to invoke this `main()` function explicitly or completely remove the class and the main function declaration.

Comment: The above one will work for copying from local to S3. Is there any way to copy from S3 bucket to another bucket. Uploading from local will take 3 to 4 hours to upload 15 GB file as S3 servers located at different location